# SwiftMailer silently ignores errors when messages fail delivery

Tags: php, email, symfony, smtp, swiftmailer

When run from inside controller and when in-memory spooling is configured via `spool: { type: memory }`  swiftmailer seems to work like this:

- whenever from within controller `mailer->send($message)` is called -> save message in memory
- when controller has finished work and symfony Kernel is about to shutdown (somwehere in event `kernel.terminate` or smth) - check messages saved in memory and _actually submit them to SMTP-server

However this last step seems to silently ignore any errors which may be thrown when peforming submitting of the message to the SMTP server.

I discovered that errors are silently swallowed when I was setting up SMTP from Amazon SES, and have made wrong configuration:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
# For illustration I put WRONG port 9999, which means that this should trigger
# error (correct port would be 587)
mailer_port: 9999
mailer_encryption: tls
mailer_host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
mailer_user: SES_USER_KEY
mailer_password: SES_USER_SECRET
```

Now, if I attempt to send email using wrong configuration **from a symfony Command, just as expected I get `Swift_TransportException`** and error is NOT silently ignored. (From my observations it seems that symfony commands do NOT use memory-spooling and attempt to send messages immediately)

Below is sample of the command (so you're sure I am doing it right).

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
     $email = $input->getArgument('email');
     $content = $this->getHelper('dialog')->ask($output, 'Please input content:');

     $emsg = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
     $emsg->setTo($email);
     $emsg->setFrom('d@my-ses-verified-domain.com');
     $emsg->setSubject('This is subject');
     $emsg->setBody($content);

     $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($emsg);
}
```

And here's command output when the exception `Swift_TransportException` is thrown:

```
ubuntu@localhost:~/my-app$ console acme:email:send existing@email.com
We are going to send email to :existing@email.com

Please input content:asdf adf


[Swift_TransportException]                                                                                    
Connection could not be established with host email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

Hovewer if I attempt to send email from controller, then I see no error messages. Basically this means that in case there's an error (misconfiguration or network error or SMTP server down), all the emails I sent will silently disappear without any trace (no exception thrown, no error loggged in `dev.log` neither in `prod.log`).

How can I force `Swiftmailer` to leave trace of failed delivery attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to force the delivery of the emails by flushing the spooler manually, which should then allow you to catch the exception and log as needed. I found an example in the docs here (modified for the context of a controller)...

https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html

```
$message = new \Swift_Message();

// ... prepare the message

$mailer = $this->get('mailer');

$mailer->send($message);

// now manually flush the queue
$spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
$transport = $this->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');

$spool->flushQueue($transport);
```

While the example was originally for use in the console environment, I see no reason why it wouldn't be valid in a controller.

**Edit:**

Another way to log the exception would be to utilize the Swiftmailer event system. This involves creating a custom plugin (as a service would be best) that implements `\Swift_Events_TransportExceptionListener`, then registering it with the mailer.

For example, the custom plugin class:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\SwiftPlugin;

use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger;

class SwiftExceptionLoggerPlugin implements \Swift_Events_TransportExceptionListener
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Invoked as a TransportException is thrown in the Transport system.
     *
     * @param Swift_Events_TransportExceptionEvent $evt
     */
    public function exceptionThrown(\Swift_Events_TransportExceptionEvent $evt)
    {
        $e = $evt->getException();
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        $this->logger->err(sprintf("Swiftmailer Exception: %s", $message));
    }
}
```

Then add this as a service along with the `swiftmailer.default.plugin` tag. That will automatically register it as a Swiftmailer plugin...

```
<service id="acme.demo.swift_plugin.swift_exception_logger_plugin" class="Acme\DemoBundle\SwiftPlugin\SwiftExceptionLoggerPlugin">
    <tag name="swiftmailer.default.plugin" />
    <argument type="service" id="logger" />
</service>
```

This will log the exception message in the standard log area for dev/prod. However, if the timeout takes very long to occur I think it still may not log correctly if the user clicks away or closes their browser/tab, etc. Perhaps the above along with setting a lower timeout value for Swiftmailer via the `mailer_timeout` parameter.

Comment: I just tried and this method _does_ work in controller, and as expected it will throw an exception upon failed delivery attempt. So it solves half of my problem, but introduces annoying "side effect": controller blocks for delivery which in the worst case scenario: when SMTP server is down, this will block for 30 seconds... making user abandon my app. The "in-memory" spooling allowed controller to return page before attempting "long-running" delivery... I wonder if there's still any way to combine the two: deferred delivery and still having errors in the logs.

Comment: @DimitryK I have updated my answer with another way of logging the exceptions which might work a little better.

Comment: BINGO! Adding Swift exception listener worked to intercept `Swift_TransportException` here's my `dev.log` line  `[2014-12-02 09:02:15] app.ERROR: Swiftmailer Exception: Connection could not be established with host INVALID_email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0] [] []`.

Comment: Also first I tagged my  `SwiftExceptionLoggerPlugin` _incorrectly_  with `swiftmailer.default_plugin` (see the _ underscore?) instead of tagging with correct tag `swiftmailer.default.plugin` (see the . dot?). So just a watchout for people to be careful with typing :)

Comment: I also checked whether misconfiguring port (using 465, which on SES is open but will timeout) will trigger timeout exception. And it did, just as expected: `[2014-12-02 09:19:56] app.ERROR: Swiftmailer Exception: Connection to tcp://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465 Timed Out [] []`. My user received the HTML contents of the page instantly, but PHP-script kept running for another 10 seconds on the server, waiting for the timeout and after that threw exception and logged it.